# Translating when speakers reference themselves by name 

Tags: translation

In some cultures, people might call themselves by their name.

For example, if a woman's name is May, she might say in her native language

> May has a very important thing to say.

When translated to English, should it be changed to

> I have a very important thing to say.

in order to coincide with the common practices of spoken English? Or should it be left in the third person, to more accurately reflect the original utterance?

Comment: This question is too basic for the site; also, requests for help with translation are off topic. Please see the [faq] for help improving your question.

Comment: but there is a translation tag.

Comment: Hello Sarawut! Currently there is a widespread concern over  purging the translation tag. See waiwai933's proposal  http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2664/why-do-we-have-a-translation-tag

Comment: I'd use '[Hello; for those of you who don't know me, I'm May Hargreaves. I have] a very important thing to say.'  Pragmatics is important, and the original doesn't sound quirky / tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Why bother with the “for those of you who don’t know me”? She is May Hargreaves whether people know her or not.

Comment: @Anton For the same reason I'd choose 'Do you think you could close ...' instead of 'Please close ...'. Pragmatics is important, and conversation-lubricants, while semantically unnecessary, can be invaluable. Brits usually mention the weather at the start of a conversation, even though it's usually semantically unnecessary.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Things are warming up at last in central Scotland - even a bit of sunshine today, so I have to agree with you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is known as:

> [***illeism***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/illeism): *The practice of referring to oneself in the third person.*

And while this is not a common practice among native speakers, it is certainly not unheard of.  Bob Dole, the republican candidate for president of the United States in 1996 was [famous for it](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/authors/b/bob_dole.html).

> If something happened along the route and you had to leave your children with Bob Dole or Bill Clinton, I think you would probably leave them with Bob Dole.  *-Bob Dole*

Be aware though that when it is done it is usually done for comic effect because people will take notice and think it strange.

Comment: If the author's intent is illeism, translation would need to respect that. Even otherwise so. See my answer.

Comment: Consider this text: "May has something important to say. May has lost May's shoes, and May's feet hurt. May doesn't like that." This would not be reasonable English. That is, the illeism *does* look comical and *is* perceived as strange -- do it only if that's something you want to convey.

Answer (score 6):

If the author's ***intent*** is [illeism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/illeism), translation would need to respect that. If there is *no other way* of expressing oneself in the native language, then it becomes a matter of style: it would be reasonable to express natural native language in natural English.

Illeism is a rhetorical device in English. Jim's [Bob Dole quote](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/81069/18696) illustrates this: Dole was using the third person to refer to himself as though *he were someone else* comparing the two. Where that's *not* the intent in the native language, why make it so in English? You will drawing attention to it.

On the other hand, it's also reasonable to preserve the structure of the native language in the English translation, particularly if you are indicating the use of a foreign language or the product of the speaker's self-translation. Hercule Poirot's dialogue is a little odd to native English speakers, for example. Use your judgement you should.<sup>1</sup>

1: http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/002173.html

Comment: Absolutely. It simply becomes a question of the purpose of your translation: is it to convey what the speaker conveyed, or is it to stay faithful to the grammatical constructions and idioms of the speaker's native language? There are instances when the latter is useful, but almost always it's not the point. Almost always, you should do your best to understand the meaning and connotations of the original speech, and try to convey the same in the target language. (Whether or not you do things like footnote, or change difficult cultural references, etc. is up to your judgement!)

Answer (score -3):

Though apparently out of ELU's scope, let me say:

*When translated to English, should it be changed?*  **No.**

Translation needs to preserve the intent and tone of the original. There never is a reason enough to consider rewriting the example sentence with an '*I*' replacing the name.

For a better insight, you may try writersSE or other sites where translation is the main focus.